# android development how to create action bar

Tags: android, api, android-actionbar

i am creating android development with an action bar using API 15 but  the problem is that i want the action bar to be on the top of the screen . in my case the action is down the screen   anyone can help me ???

## ActionBarTest.java

```
package com.lebdev.actionbardemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ActionBarTest extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_action_bar_test);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar_test, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.iSearch:
            search();
            return true;

        case R.id.iPhoto:
            photo();
            return true;

        case R.id.iVideo:
            video();
            return true;
        default:

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void video() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "This is video function", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void photo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "This is photo function", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    private void search() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "This is search function", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

## activity_action_bar_test.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ActionBarTest" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

## String.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">ActionBarDemo</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="tsearch">Search</string>
    <string name="tphoto">Photo</string>
    <string name="tvideo">Video</string>

</resources>
```

## menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/iSearch"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/tsearch">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/iPhoto"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/tphoto">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/iVideo"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/tvideo">
    </item>

</menu>
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html read here

Comment: This is a bad design, Android Does not recommend Action bar at bottom .

Comment: @Brontok That's why he wants the Action bar at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Use your code like this..

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/iSearch"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="@string/tsearch">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/iPhoto"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="@string/tphoto">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/iVideo"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="@string/tvideo">
</item>
```

And let me know..

Comment: @ user2586685 it still show the action bar at the buttom of the screen

Comment: wait let me check again

Comment: Hey, I used same code with some changes....please refer edited ans.
And its working fine....

Comment: The change is only android:showAsAction="always|withText" in your code....now let me know if you got any problem

Comment: @ user2586685 it still the same  problemmmmmm   the action bar show at the button of the screen

Comment: okk... Which version you are using in emulator.??
Actually actionbar works fine with version 3.7 or higher that is API level 11 or higher.
So try once in version 4.0 and let me know if any problem..

Comment: i am using api level 15  version 4.0.3

Comment: sorry men...I tried the same code in my emulator as well.. and its working fine.....

Comment: so what is wrong with my emulator  i need it to be at the top of the screen not in the buttom

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38406/discussion-between-ankit-and-lebdev)

Answer (score 0):

if the minimum sdk of your android app is "API 15"

```
 android:minSdkVersion="15"
```

Then you can use ActionBar which was introduced in Api level 11

or you can use [ActionBar (Github)](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar)